# Separation of an integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose I have the following integral, with $a$, $b$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ constants and $f(x)$ monotone increasing, continuous, always positive, and bounded on $[\alpha,\beta]$.

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(x)^{ab} \, dx$$

Is is possible to separate this integral into:

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)^a \, dx\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)^b \, dx$$

If so, what are the conditions under which this can be done?

NOTE: This is not a homework problem.

EDIT: Fixed non-essential typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the simple case $f(x)=x$ leads to the complicated equation, $${\beta^{ab+1}-\alpha^{ab+1}\over ab+1}={\beta^{a+1}-\alpha^{a+1}\over a+1}{\beta^{b+1}-\alpha^{b+1}\over b+1}$$ and I don't think you are going to find any nice conditions for when this does and doesn't hold. Simplify even further by taking the special case $\alpha=0$, and you will find that, given $a$ and $b$, the equation holds if and only if $$\beta=\left({ab+1\over(a+1)(b+1)}\right)^{1/(ab-a-b-1)}$$

Another special case, $f(x)=e^x$, leads to $$e^{ab\beta}-e^{ab\alpha}=(e^{a\beta}-e^{a\alpha})(e^{b\beta}-e^{b\alpha})$$ which looks a little neater but it still doesn't seem to be easy to say anything useful about it.

Answer (score 1):

Not in some cases.

For example, take 
$$\int x^6 dx$$
By your method, $f(x)=x$, $a=2$, $b=3$:
$$\int x^{2 \times 3}dx=\int x^6dx$$
$$\int x^6 dx=(?)\int (x^2)^3 dx=\left( \int x^2 dx \right) \left( \int x^3 dx \right)$$
But
$$\frac{x^7}{7}+C\neq \left(\frac{x^3}{3} \times \frac{x^4}{4}\right)+C$$

Make it a definite integral and the same thing applies.

You can see that the same thing happens in other cases. I haven't found one where your method works.

---

Actually, take your example:
$$\int f(x)^{ab}dx=\frac{f(x)^{ab+1}}{ab}+C$$
But
$$\left( \int f(x)^a dx\right) \left( \int f(x)^b dx \right)=\left(\frac{f(x)^{a+1}}{a+1} \right) \left(\frac{f(x)^{b+1}}{b+1} \right)=\frac{f(x)^{a+b+2}}{(a+1)(b+1)}$$
Which does not necessarily equal the first result.

Comment: $\int f^a\,dx=(a+1)^{-1}f^{a+1}$ is nonsense for most functions $f$. E.g., it doesn't even work for $f(x)=x^2$, $a=1$.

Comment: I doubt that this will apply universally, as per examples above, but I'm curious to see if there are cases in which it would apply or if it is possible to disprove it.